How to remove all background shading/color in the heatmap
I'm trying to render a echart heatmap that has no background color within the grid/chart frame. I've tried every property possible and set it to false or transparent but no luck.
Here's what it looks like now and i want all the gray/alernating grid lines and shading gone.
function App(){
   return (
      <EChart
         backgroundColor={'transparent'} // Remove background color
         tooltip={{
            //position: 'top'
            show: false
         }}
         style={{
            height: '600px',
            width: '40%'
         }}
         grid={{
            show: false,
            background: 'transparent'
            //height: '50%',
            //top: '10%'
         }}
         xAxis={{
            type: 'category',
            data: days,
            splitArea: {
               show: true
            }
         }}
         yAxis={{
            type: 'category',
            data: hours,
            splitArea: {
               show: true
            }
         }}
         visualMap={{
            min: 0,
            max: 10,
            calculable: true,
            orient: 'horizontal',
            left: 'center',
            bottom: '0%',
            textStyle: {
               color: 'white'
            },
            inRange: {
               color: ['#f6ffed', '#b7eb8f', '#73d13d', '#389e0d', '#135200'] // Custom color palette try https://ant.design/docs/spec/colors#programmatic-usage
            }
         }}
         textStyle={{
            color: 'white'
         }}
         series={[
            {
               name: 'Tweets By Day By Hour',
               type: 'heatmap',
               data: data,
               shading: false,
               itemStyle: {
                  color: 'transparent' // Make background bars transparent
               },
               label: {
                  show: true,
                  color: 'black'
               },
               emphasis: {
                  itemStyle: {
                     shadowBlur: 10,
                     shadowColor: 'transparent',
                     color: 'transparent'
                  }
               }
            }
         ]}
      />
   )
}

a empty chart with no background color or shading

For the heatmap to remove the background/shading inside the chart, try to configure or customize the xAxis and yAxis splitArea/splitLine:
 xAxis: {
        type: "category",
        data: filledTimestamps,

        splitArea: {
          show: false, //hide the shaded area
          
        },
        splitLine: {
          show: true, //show the lines
          lineStyle:{
            color: #ffff, //line color
          }
        },
    },
     yAxis: {
        type: "category",
        data: sortedYAxisArray,
        splitArea: {
          show: false,
         
        },
        splitLine: {
          show: true
          lineStyle:{
            color: "#ffff"
          }
        },

      },

